# How to statistically compare two ordinal variables to find out the best one?

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a dataset with two columns, each column representing a score of 1, 2, and 3. [(Here is the Dataset)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IYgQtqJrKgnEHGeAlmWVunf7K9AUDzz-) The ranks of first column is changed (or not changed) in the second column due to a process. If I add the scores for each column, then I can know which column represent better score. But can I make a statistically significance test to know which column is better? In other means, can I test the hypothesis that the second column significantly shows better score than the first column?

I have done two-tailed Wilcoxon Signed Rank test. This can test the hypothesis that the mean difference of these two columns is similar. Does a one-tail test result of Wilcoxon Signed Rank test represent that which column is better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to carefully (thoughtfully) define "better"; it's easily possible for two different definitions of better to give quite different results.

Comment: It sounds like the signed-rank test is appropriate for your purposes.  But your question is unclear to me.  It might be helpful to reexamine the uses of one-tail and two-tailed tests, for example [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-the-differences-between-one-tailed-and-two-tailed-tests/).  In the case of your data, the direction of change from Col. 1 to Col. 2 is so overwhelming that either tailed test will come to the same conclusion.  By my count, 171 obs. increased, 131 were the same, and 6 decreased.  You could use that as a type of effect size.

Comment: @Glen_b, I meant the word "better" for representing which column provide an overall improvement of score.

Comment: @SalMangiafico, your reasoning sounds perfect for this case. I was thinking that if there is any way to say that the overall observation is "significantly" increased or remained same or decreased. However, one-tail test should not be used here. I would go with the effect size.

Comment: No, you can use the signed-rank test for a test of significance.  (I would use a two-tailed test, but it doesn't matter much). And report the percentage of increases as a kind of effect size statistic.

Comment: @sbhadra in effect you've simply replaced one vague (not-explicitly-defined) word for better (*better*) by another (*improvement*). This is not at all what I mean by "thoughtfully". You need to be clear about exactly what sense you mean 'better' or 'improvement' (or any other synonym you can think of). Ideally you would give an *operational* definition that relates to your actual needs, but at the very least you should explain what aspect of better you intend. For example, higher on average is a quite different criterion than "more likely to be the higher".